# Typo3 Neos: How to pass parameter from typoscript using 'TYPO3.Neos:Plugin'?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-flow, neoscms

i wanted to pass a parameter dynamically via aloha editor, i have select box like this on .yaml

```
properties:
 events:
  type: string
  ui:
    label: 'Events'
    reloadIfChanged: TRUE
    inspector:
      group: 'document'
      editor: 'TYPO3.Neos/Inspector/Editors/SelectBoxEditor'
      editorOptions:
        dataSourceUri: 'events/list'
```

and on .ts2 file i use this

```
prototype(Festival.Backend:Events) < prototype(TYPO3.Neos:Plugin) {
    package = 'Festival.Backend'
    controller = 'Events'
    action = 'ast_view'
    artist = ${q(node).property('events')}
}
```

in this tutorial http://docs.typo3.org/neos/TYPO3NeosDocumentation/Appendixes/NeosTypoScriptReference.html#
it says that i can pass a parameter to the controller using

```
argumentNamespace:
[key]:
```

my question is how do i add the 'artist' value from node property to the controller action?
something like this

```
public function ast_viewAction($artist) {
    $this->view->assign('artist', $artist); 
}
```

thanks for your attention

EDIT: solved thanks to [Aske Ertmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2311403/aske-ertmann), change my function to this

```
 public function ast_viewAction() {
    $events_artist = $this->request->getInternalArgument('__artist');
    $this->view->assign('artist', $artist); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments from the TypoScript plugin object is available as internal arguments on the request, which is available in the controller action.

```
/** @var \TYPO3\TYPO3CR\Domain\Model\Node $currentNode */
$currentNode = $this->request->getInternalArgument('__node');
```

A few additional tips can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/revsbech/8a9f11b970796017ed54)

Comment: i'm sorry i'm currently new to this framework and i'm afraid i didn't really understand. Which line should i put inside/outside the 'ast_viewAction' function?